# Formatting date to desired format in batch file

Tags: batch, ldap

I am running a batch file as

```
@echo off
set yy=%date:~-4%
set mm=%date:~-7,2%
set dd=%date:~-10,2%
set MYDATE=%dd%%mm%%yy%
md UserRecords%MYDATE%

cd E:\testuser\OpenDJ-2.5.0-Xpress1\bat
ldapsearch -h localhost -p 1389 -D "cn=Directory Manager" -w password -b "ou=people,dc=exmple,dc=com" inetUserstatus=Active dn sn createTimestamp lastlogintime inetUserstatus>"E:\testuser\records\UserRecords%MYDATE%\userlist_%MYDATE%.txt" --trustAll
```

But the date format in createTimestamp and lastlogintime is not like I want to record.

At present it is like : `lastlogindate: 20130309100231Z`

But i want it in a general format : `dd/mm/yyyy`.

Is it possible to do that? 
I tried modifying it in the password policy of OpenDj but when i change the format it does not display the field in console.
Please Help!!

Comment: can't you use `set MYDATE=%dd%-%mm%-%yy%` ?

Comment: @BhaveshGangani Oops, yeah, i read that wrong too. The OP wants the "lastlogindate" generated by `ldapsearch` in his desired format. Not the `%MYDATE%`-variable in the batch.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://opendj.forgerock.org/opendj-server/doc/admin-guide/index/chap-ldap-operations.html)

Did you try:

```
dsconfig
 ... < other options >
 --set last-login-time-attribute:lastLoginTime
 --set last-login-time-format:"dd/MM/yyyy"
```

before executing `ldapsearch`?

If that doesn't work it could be the `lastLoginTime` needs to meet some requirements. You could try `"ddMMyyyyZ"` instead.

---

From [that source](http://opendj.forgerock.org/opendj-server/doc/admin-guide/index/chap-ldap-operations.html):

> Next, adjust the password policy to put a generalized time stamp on lastLoginTime.

```
$ dsconfig
 -p 4444
 -h `hostname`
 -D "cn=Directory Manager"
 -w password
 set-password-policy-prop
 --policy-name "Default Password Policy"
 --set last-login-time-attribute:lastLoginTime
 --set last-login-time-format:"yyyyMMddHHmmss'Z'"
 -X -n
```